# is it safe to use Trigonometric of large number in pocket scientific calculator

Tags: trigonometry, angle, calculator, mathematical-astronomy

[image: Screenshot of book]

In this [book](https://openlibrary.org/books/OL389940M/Astronomical_algorithms) (from 90s), there is a suggestion to reduce angle interval down to between 0 and 360 degrees, when the angle is larger than $360^\text{o}$ or when the angle is negative.

So here is my question:
Can modern calculators (e.g. Casio 350-ms) safely calculate trigonometric functions of large number without me having to manually reduce it first?

I tried several times and the result is same (without reducing it), but I am still not sure.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You should choose your tags carefully. What has this to do with [tag:mathematical-astronomy]?

Comment: Looking at the link, it seems that the book referenced is about mathematical astronomy @JoséCarlosSantos

Comment: The mathematical-astronomy tag seems perfectly reasonable here. ¶ My guess is that any modern calculator should have no problem with trigonometric functions of angles produced by typical solar system theories, at least for Julian dates within a few hundred years (beyond which many of these theories are no longer valid, I would also guess).  But I suppose it would help to know which theory you're trying to calculate.

Comment: Ahh, I see, this calculation is from the "Solar Coordinates" chapter of Meeus's book.  I don't know if your version is older, or mine is, but in my edition, this material is in reference to a calculation in Chapter $25$, not $24$.  I don't think this is the full VSOP$87$.  I suspect you're fine not reducing the angles modulo $360$ degrees.

Comment: I would also try computing the sine of $-35999970$ degrees.  You should also get $0.5$.

Comment: @BrianTung yes it is reduce version of VSOP87 for solar coordinates, and yes −35999970 is equal 0.5 in my calculator

Comment: Desmos (a popular online calculator) can be made to give errors with sines: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/kqpob7khmf . It also has trouble with sin(-35999970) in degree mode. I suspect these are both floating point errors.